# Invoke-Command in a background job

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, start-job

I have a powershell 2.0 script which should run a command on several servers and process the output.
I want to run the command and the processing for each server in a background job.

The comand works without any problems and terminates within half a second or less:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $client -ScriptBlock { #do some stuff }
```

But when I run this in a background job, the job doesn't terminate:

```
Start-Job { Invoke-Command -ComputerName $client -ScriptBlock { #do some stuff } }
```

Has someone a idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you should do it the other way:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849698.aspx

> To run a background job on a remote computer, use the AsJob parameter
>   that is available on many cmdlets, or **use the Invoke-Command cmdlet to
>   run a Start-Job command on the remote computer**. For more information,
>   see about_Remote_Jobs.

Comment: But this runs the job on the remote computer. I want to run the job on the executing computer and process the output from the invoke-command in this job.

Comment: @bones I think the effect is the same. `Invoke-Command` should kick off the job on the remote machine and return immediately. You can use `Receive-Job -ComputerName` to get the result.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use Start-Job to run invoke-command so that I can watch and handle the jobs on the central machine using Get-Job.

When I loop through the "list of remote computers" I use the "current computer name" as the -Name parameter in the Start-Job so that I can watch each job individually and as a group.

Just my two cents from experience.

Edit Example:

```
$job =
{ 
    $remoteJob = { ##Do Stuff Here }
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $args[0] -ScriptBlock $remoteJob
}
Start-Job -Name <jobName> -ScriptBlock $job -ArgumentList <remoteComputer>
```

To your question about why the Job "never finishes" I don't have input other than, make sure the code you are running remotely does actually end.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This will also work, at least in Powershell 5

```
invoke-command -asjob -computer $PC -scriptblock { ## do stuff }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Latest version of PS you can create a New Session and use it with Invoke-Command start-job cmdlets instead of using the ComputerName arguments directly.

```
$s = new-pssession -computername Server01
invoke-command -session $s -scriptblock { start-job -scriptblock {get-eventlog system}}
```