# what is wrong with this Start-Job command?

Tags: powershell, jobs

Edit: Ok, that's weird. Maybe I just screwed up my testing. The command that I indicated does work. What doesn't is using it within a Foreach loop within the ISE (version 4). Within a regular Powershell console, it also does work.

`foreach ($computer in @("2008R2-test","anotherServer")) {  Start-Job -name $computer -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Command -computerName $computer -scriptBlock {$?} } }`

The job never stops running, never is "completed". I don't get the cursor back. It hangs and I have to kill the ISE with task manager to get it back. The "$?" is just an example of running anything. I'm trying to do it this way because I want to run some commands that will display stuff to the screen, then do stuff that can happen in the background including a command that runs at the remote machine. I guess it's just another case of not being able to use the ISE.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696149/invoke-command-in-a-background-job

Comment: this is running your script block on a remote computer, you should not get any console output from the `invoke-command -computer xxx` line. This is expected behavior. You can have your script block print output to text file and get it back to you.

Comment: The invoke-computer command against a remote machine most defintely gives console output. And my initial understanding was wrong; so, this thread is kind of moot unless one reads the current version of the original post.